# How to create a dynamic lambda to use it?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, foreach, expression

I've learned to manipulate Dynamic lambda expressions with the Expression class.
However, the lambda expression used in a ForEach method (`LINQ`) seems a little different since it's an assign.

For exemple, doing this :

```
myList.ForEach(x => x.Status = "OK") ;
```

will update the Status property of each object in the myList list.

How to accomplish it using Expression object? I didn't find any method in Expression to set a property... Is it used only for retrieving properties values ?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? V4 has it, while earlier versions don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assignment *does* exist in expression trees (see [`Expression.Assign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268005.aspx)) as of .NET 4 (where it's used to support `dynamic`), but it's not supported by the C# compiler, which still only supports genuine "expressions" for lambda expression conversions to expression trees.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Linq Expressions does not support assigning. I think you'd need to write a method with assignment in it and put that in the expression.

**Update**: Looks like assignment *is* supported as of .NET 4. See Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
myList.ForEach(x =>
{
    x.Status = "OK";
});
```

or

```
Action<YourType> oSetter = x =>
{
    x.Status = "OK";
});
myList.ForEach(oSetter);
```

Comment: You just said the same thing as the OP.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. Ok.